# Script to hide columns based on the first row value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am asking for help with a script to conditionally hide/unhide columns in a spreadsheet.

Sample sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NXEQJEc9mY9X1kL3pUQH-9CyxvRTdjG5uaQbjsJAmHk/edit#gid=2059155770

I need a script that will trigger on the edit of the =Sheet1!A1:A4 range and will hide all columns across the spreadsheet that have "False" value in row 1 and show all columns that have "true" value in row 1.

Is it possible? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to hide the columns of the sheet "Hide sheet" by the values of 1st row, when the checkboxes of the cells "A1:A4" on "Sheet1" are changed.
- You want to know whether above goal can be achieved using Google Apps Script with the OnEdit event trigger.

At first, I think that your goal can be achieved using Google Apps Script with the OnEdit event trigger.

#### Flow:

The flow of this sample script is as follows.

1. Check whether the checkboxes are edited.
2. Retrieve the values of the 1st row of sheet "Hide sheet", and the columns are hidden or shown by the values.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the container-bound script of your shared Spreadsheet. And please modify the checkbox of the cells "A1:A4" on "Sheet1". By this, `onEdit` is executing and the script is run.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sheetName = "Hide sheet";  // If you want to change the sheet name, please modify this.
  
  // 1. Check whether the checkboxes are edited.
  const ss = e.source;
  const range = e.range;
  const activeSheet = range.getSheet();
  if (activeSheet.getSheetName() != "Sheet1" || !["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4"].some(f => f == range.getA1Notation())) return;
  
  // 2. Retrieve the values of the 1st row of sheet "Hide sheet", and the columns are hidden or shown by the values.
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  sheet
    .getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn())
    .getValues()[0]
    .forEach((e, i) => sheet[e === true ? "showColumns" : "hideColumns"](i + 1));
}
```

#### Note:

- In this sample script, the OnEdit event trigger is used as the simple trigger. So when you directly run the script at the script editor, an error occurs. Because the event object `e` is not returned. So please be careful this.
- Please use this script with enabling V8.

#### References:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)